# Electric field strength for a rod vs a wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current

I've found some equations which I should be able to use to calculate the electric field of a uniformly charged rod.  What I was wondering was if I could use this to calculate the electric field strength around a wire.  I realized that there may be an issue with that because the charged rod is assumed to have a stationary amount of charge while the charge in a wire would be moving.  An ampere is one coulomb of charge per second, so for a one meter wire that's conducting one amp of electricity, could I simply convert that to one coulomb per meter and use that as charge density, then calculate the electric field the way I would for a charged rod?  I was using [this equation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elelin.html) for the charged rod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard conversion of current to charge density because a wire can be neutral (in fact, most are) and still transport charges.

If all the negative charges are moving one way and the positive charges standing still, there's still a current even though the wire is neutral.

Comment: Oh.  So you're saying that a wire with a certain current wouldn't necessarily have an electric field.  It would still have a magnetic field, right?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: Well don't I feel silly.  Just learning this stuff I guess.